# leaflet load markers and pop ups from external file

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I am currently building a leaflet map where I will implement a bunch of markers with popups.
I want all of my markers and popups stored in an external file to keep the code as clean as possible. My question is, how can I achieve this? Do I create a geojson file with the markers and popups and if so, how do I load such a geojson into my html file if I want the geojson file to be stored locally (avoiding CORS policy error) ? What other options do I have?
Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit your geojson data here: https://geojson.io/ and then create a js file where you assign your geojson data (copied from geojson.io) to a variable:

```
var geojsondata = ... // your geojson data
```

Then create a html file with another js file, where you read and display your geojson (read the leaflet documentation for more info):

```
var readfromjson = L.geoJSON(geojsondata).addTo(map);
```

That is how you load markers. If you want to have also popups to every marker you need to add some properties to every marker by creating a table in geojson.io with the table name popup for example (a popup to one marker could be 'I am a popup' (must be html)). Now to access these properties in your code:

```
var readfromjson = L.geoJSON(geojsondata, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {   
        if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popup) {
            layer.bindPopup(features.properties.popup)            
      
        }
    }
}).addTo(map);
```